# Python plot a separate line for each line of data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph from a csv using matplotlib and pandas with the following structure:
[image]

There are 36 total possible states and I would like each of them to be have one line. There are 100 Iterations. Iteration will start from 0 and is increased by 1 each time. Every state will have a record for every ith iteration. The lines are plotted with Iteration as the x axis and Utility as the y axis, visualized below.
[image]

I've made a dataframe out of the csv file but that is as far as I've gotten.

```
value_headers = ['State', 'Iteration', 'Utility']
value_df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', names = value_headers, index_col='State')
```

**EDIT**: [Here is the dict of my dataframe](https://pastebin.com/WZmzvDHr)

I've been wrecking by brain on this for the past hour to no avail. I don't even know how to describe this problem in a concise sentence for troubleshooting. Also, I wasn't able to find a question similar to mine on stackoverflow. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can reproduce this problem. Please provide the .csv (or at least some line of it) or alternatively provide the code to create a DataFrame containing this data. Additionally, please provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you mean by "Iteration as the x axis and Utility as the y axis". These look like just 1 number each for each row in your data - how does that map to the line that you want to plot?

Comment: I don't think it's possible for me to share the .csv file, so I'm working on re-creating the dataframe from scratch right now

Comment: hey @eandklahn, I've made an edit to my question

Comment: By the way in order to generate the DataFrame just read the .csv in your program using `df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")`and then use `print(df.to_dict())` to print to console. This dictionary as printed to the console can then be used to create the dataframe.

Comment: @Mushroomator got it thank you, I've updated my post with a link to the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your DataFrame correctly, you need to figure out when a given state identifier appears in the first column of your csv and then use those values together to make a plot.
Based on your example with a single value of `Iteration`, I suggest the following (assuming your DataFrame is called `df`)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df = df.iloc[1:,:]
df = df.reset_index()
# the state identifier is now a column with the header 'index'
for idx in df['index'].unique():
    subset = df[df['index']==idx]
    ax.plot(subset['Iteration'], subset['Utility'])
plt.show()
```